# Do i Need to fine tune the last convolutional layers in a state of art CNN models like ResNet50?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

My graduation project is to use transfer learning on a CNN model that can diagnose Covid-19 from Chest X-ray images. After spending days Fine tuning the hyper parameters such as the number of fully connected layers, the number of nodes in the layers, the learning rate, and the drop rate using Keras tuner library with Bayesian Optimizer, I got some very good results, A test accuracy of 98% for multi class classification and a 99% for binary class classification. However, i froze all the layers in the original base model. I only fine tuned the last Fully connected layers after exhaustive hyper parameter optimization. Most articles and papers out there say that they fine the fully connected layers as well as some of the convolutional layers. Am i doing something wrong? I am afraid that this is too good to be true.

My data set is not that big, only 7000 images taken from the Kaggle Covid-19 competition.

I used image enhancement techniques such as N-CLAHE on the images before the training and the classification which improved the accuracy significantly compared to not enhancing the images.

I did the same for multiple State of art models, such as VGG-16 and ResNet50, and they all gave me superb results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by "only fine tuned the last Fully connected layers" then **NO**, you did not.

You can choose to fine-tune any layer of your choice but most importantly the final layers of the model, which is what you did, so you're good to go.

Comment: Take VGG-16,for example. It has 5 convolutional blocks followed by 2 4096 Fully connected layers and one output layer. I removed the Fully connected layers and did hyper parameter analysis using  Bayesian Optimizer to get the optimum number of layers, nodes, learning rate,and drop out rate. Once finished,I trained the model with the obtained hyper parameters and froze the base vgg-16 model up to the last convolutional block. Hence, only the fully connected layers were trainable. What most people do, though, is include some of the convolutional layers of the base models in the training process.

Comment: Also thank for the reply, i can't like it because i am under 15 reputation.

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing wrong with your implementation. You could think of it like this; the vgg model is a feature extractor and the fully connected layer is the classifier. It is also a very common practice.

Comment: If my answer answered your question you can select it as **the answer**.

Comment: Thanks Dude, i was just worried that i got such good results. It was like too good to be True, i mean before image enhancement and Hyper parameter optimization i was like 85%~89%but then, it went to 96 and 99 in Multi-class and binary-class respectively. I went Nuts and started to overthink it.

Comment: BTW, i am trying to select your answer as the answer, but i don't know how. I am complete StackOverflow newbie

Comment: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." - SO